# refresh dynamic contents on common popup jQuery mobile

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile, web-applications, popup

I am working on a web app where, I have a Common popup  as a direct child of , it contains few popups created dynamically from the JSON. There are two separate pages having user input form. JSON file is updated using the form data.

I am updating the contents of the popups using the updated JSON in the form submit function. I am facing the problem to refresh the popup contents on form submit. I have to restart the APP to see the changes on popups.

I tried triggering 'refresh' and 'create' events on popups in form submit function, but still no result.

Moreover even if I set the contents of popup div to be empty using $('#popup-div').empty() in submit function, I can still see the popup. Don't know if this is the caching problem.

Please advice for some solution, Thanks

Example Code:

```
<body>
    <div id="common-popup">

       <div id="data-popup" data-role="popup">';
         <p>Name: N/A<p> 
         <p>DOB: N/A <p>
       </div> <!--Popup div ends -->
    </div>

    <div data-role="page" id="page1">
        <input type='text' id='p1_name' value=''>Name: </input>
        <input type='text' id='p1_dob' value=''>DOB: </input>
        <button class="update-data" id="b1"/>
       <a href="#data-popup"> Watch Data </a>
    </div>

    <div data-role="page" id="page2">
        <input type='text' id='p2_name'>Name: </input>
        <input type='text' id='p2_dob'>DOB: </input>
        <button class="update-data" id="b2"/>
        <a href="#data-popup"> Watch Data </a>
    </div>
   </body>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('.update-data').on('vclick', function(){
      var id = $(this).id;
          id = id.split('');
       var htm = '<div id="data-popup" data-role="popup">';
           htm += '<p>Name: ' + $('#p' + id[1] + '_name').val()  +'<p>';
           htm += '<p>Name: ' + $('#p' + id[1] + '_name').val()  +'<p>';

         $('#common-popup').html(htm).trigger('create');
     });

</script>
```

Comment: Please show us your code. Even better, create a jsFiddle that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @ezanker Added the example code.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/7HVGR/

Comment: @ezanker Thanks for the fiddle, but it doesn't refresh the popup contents when you update for more than once. It just shows the contents you entered for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working demo

`$( "#common-popup #data-popup")
         .enhanceWithin().popup()
         .on('popupafterclose', function(event) {
               $(this).remove();
            });`

[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7HVGR/4/)

The dynamic popup created should be removed after its closed. Creating it again and again makes multiple popups..but you are still referring to the first one, which created the problem.